# Send image to mail through phpmailer

Tags: php

I also tried to send image using PHPMailer. But it also not works. Now what i do? Here is the code.

```
<?php

require("PHPMailer.php");

$mail =new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->Username = 'sender@gmail.com';

$mail->Password = 'password';

$mail->From="sender@gmail.com";

$mail->FromName="My site's mailer";

$mail->Sender="sender@gmail.com";

$mail->AddReplyTo("recipient@gmail.com", "Replies for my site");

$mail->Subject = "Your invoice";

$mail->IsHTML(false);

$mail->AddAttachment('k.jpeg', 'koala.jpeg');

 // attach files/invoice-user-1234.pdf, and rename it to invoice.pdf

$mail->Body = "Please find your invoice attached.";

if(!$mail->Send())

{

   echo "Error sending: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;

}

else

{

   echo "Letter is sent";

}

?>
```

Comment: I hope that's not your real Gmail password. If it is, change it immediately, since it's now out there for the whole world to see.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what's not working?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\prac\phpmailer\src\sendfile.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\prac\phpmailer\src\sendfile.php on line 3 I also declare phpmailer class on to my file.

Comment: @SachinPatel Can you post the whole code? If this is your full code, you haven't included the PHPMailer class

Answer (score 0):

Kindly change the image into the base64. try this.

```
if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']) &&
$_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],
                     $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
}
```

And the function AddAttachment

```
public function AddAttachment($path,
                          $name = '',
                          $encoding = 'base64',
                          $type = 'application/octet-stream')
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can also try this

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="form_phpm_mailer.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

may be you are not using

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it a problem with the hostname of the mail server

```
$mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com'); // if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
```